# Get the all columns counts and storing the number in a variable

Tags: c#, ms-access, schema

I want to search in 3 tables in database where paname equal to text after that i used GetSchema to calculate the columns numbers in these tables to use it in for loop statement but getShema always print the 28 instead of real columns number.

> i have 50 columns in all these tables

```
            con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=labx.accdb";

            con.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT hema.*,bioche.*,immuni.* FROM [hema],[bioche],[immuni] WHERE hema.paname = @paname AND bioche.paname = @paname AND immuni.paname = @paname";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paname", textBox2.Text);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int cont = 0;

            var colCount= con.GetSchema("columns").Columns.Count; // Get the numbers of columns 

            MessageBox.Show(tables.ToString()); // print the count of these columns in a massageBox

            while (dr.Read())
            { 
                   src searchfrm = new src();
                   searchfrm.Show();

                   

                if (cont == 0)
                {
                    searchfrm.textBox1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                    searchfrm.textBox2.Text = dr[1].ToString();

                    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) // i want to use colCount here instead of 50
                    {
                       if (dr[x].ToString().Trim() != "")searchfrm.textBox3.Text += dr[x].ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;

                    }

                }

            }

            con.Close();
        
        
        }
```

Comment: I don't see the tables variable initialised.... what are you doing with the cont? Its never been changed.

Comment: `colCount` is not what you expect - it is the number of columns in the schema table of the "columns" collection; see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getschema). And the text in the message box is totally unrelated to `colCount`.

Comment: To get the number of columns in the result, you can simply use `dr.Columns.Count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number of columns in the result, you can simply use dr.Columns.Count – [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700710/get-the-all-columns-counts-and-storing-the-number-in-a-variable#comment116163775_65700710) by [Klaus Gütter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700710/get-the-all-columns-counts-and-storing-the-number-in-a-variable#comment116163775_65700710)